# Visual Basic/Studio Text Input issue (disabling certain characters)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a form with three text boxes with a 'subtotal', 'amount tendered' and 'change' box. Both subtotal and change boxes are disabled which means the user can only input numbers in the tendered box. I'm using the following code which I found from http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/blogs/5908/restricting-user-input-in-vb-net.aspx to limit the input:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

My concern is that that specific coding works for limiting the input of numbers, but it also disabled the backspace, dot and delete key. I'm fairly new to this (we only started discussing things about VB/Studio less than two weeks ago, I have no prior experience about using Keypresses but I wanted to try)

I've tried manipulating the `if` statement (and also adding if statements) by excluding the spacebar's ASCII value, only to end up with a warning about incompatible types. I can replace text by double clicking the text input when the form is running, but my app will most likely be utilizing the keyboard mainly because it is a transaction app, so the backspace and more importantly the dot is really needed. How do I exclude both from being disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sample for [Control.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the MSDN documentation, it's about 95% of what you want.

That said, be aware, there's more work to do.  What happens if someone enters 124.34.22?   You might consider a [MaskedTextBox](http://www.dotnetperls.com/maskedtextbox), but if this is an exercise for learning Visual Basic, that's pretty much cheating :)